# AWS Pinpoint APNSChannel enabling through Cloudfomration

Tags: key, aws-cloudformation, private-key, aws-pinpoint

I am trying to enable APNSChannel on Pinpoint using CloudFormation template and I am using key credentials for configuration.
I added Authentication key , which is .p8 file, as txt in this format:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyshckdyyyyyy
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But I get following error for APN when I run my stack:

```
Property validation failure: [Value for property {/DefaultAuthenticationMethod} does not match pattern {TOKEN|CERTIFICATE}]
```

Do you have any idea how can I resole the issue?

Answer (score 0):

well I just saw your question, but in case you still need the answer:

First: The AWS documentation is wrong because the values for the **DefaultAuthenticationMethod** are not **key** or **certificate**, the values are exactly what the error show **TOKEN** or **CERTIFICATE**.

Second: Copy from the .p8 file the key and remove the lines breakers or spaces and the BEGIN PRIVATE KEY and END PRIVATE KEY lines:

DefaultAuthenticationMethod: 'TOKEN'

TokenKey: 'xxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyshckdyyyyyy'